# c# refactor duplicated property setter and getter with different names

Tags: c#, properties, refactoring

I've got some public properties which other then the property names they are identical. Im just wondering if there is a cleaner way since there seems to be a lot repeated code there. Here is an example:

```
    public static bool Property1
    {
        get => LocalSettingsService.RetrieveSetting<bool>();
        set => LocalSettingsService.SaveSetting<bool>(value);
    }

    public static bool Property2
    {
        get => LocalSettingsService.RetrieveSetting<bool>();
        set => LocalSettingsService.SaveSetting<bool>(value);
    }        
    public static bool Property3
    {
        get => LocalSettingsService.RetrieveSetting<bool>();
        set => LocalSettingsService.SaveSetting<bool>(value);
    }
    public static bool Property4
    {
        get => LocalSettingsService.RetrieveSetting<bool>();
        set => LocalSettingsService.SaveSetting<bool>(value);
    }
```

The RetrieveSetting and SaveSetting methods pull the CallingMemberName to do it's thing.

Any tricks on chopping down the repeated code?

Comment: Couldy you just have `GetSetting<T>(string name)` and `SetSetting<T>(string name, T value)`?

Comment: @tymtam We would lose our intellisense on the property names if we went down that path

Comment: What's the advantage of having `GetSetting` and `SetSetting` use reflection?

Comment: If Property1 == Property2 == Property3 == Property4 , Why not just use a same property ? and declare a generic name

Answer (score 0):

### Aesthetics

If it's about aesthetics, then you could just rename things.

```
public static bool Property1 { get => LSL.Get<bool>(); set => LSL.Set(value); }
public static string Property2 { get => LSL.Get<string>(); set => LSL.Set(value); }
public static int Property3 { get => LSL.Get<int>(); set => LSL.Set(value); }
public static uint Property4 { get => LSL.Get<uint>(); set => LSL.Set(value); }
```

`SaveSetting`...erm... I mean `Set` should not need the type as it can be inferred from the type of `value`.

---

### `IOptions<TOptions>`

If you're after something more you could look at `IOptions<TOptions>` pattern from [.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.0).